# Spring @EnableScheduling and @Schedule annotation don't work

Tags: java, spring, scheduling

I have made a class with a method inside which should run every 5 seconds. They look like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class MyClass {
    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
    public void myMethod() {
        logger.info("hi");
    }
}
```

The problem is that it is called only once at the beginning and never again.

Comment: with spring boot

Comment: Try adding `@EnableScheduling` on the `main` spring boot java file and remove from `MyClass`

Comment: One thing to make sure is that you never let any exception of any kind escape from the scheduled method - doing so will stop your scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

I have just created Spring boot app from Spring Initializr and it works perfectly. You could check following code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
    public void myMethod() {
        System.out.println("hi  " + new Date());
    }
}
```

Dependencies:

```
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Output:

```
hi  Mon Sep 16 12:26:56 EEST 2019
hi  Mon Sep 16 12:27:01 EEST 2019
hi  Mon Sep 16 12:27:06 EEST 2019
```

Update:
It also works with separated config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class Config {
    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
    public void myMethod() {
        System.out.println("hi  " + new Date());
    }
}

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers to this question indicate that in general the `@Scheduled` works. but it has some limitations - such time interval could be given as milliseconds only or as cron expression. And that is not always user-friendly. I opted into writing my own custom scheduler. It requires a bit more work than just using annotation but provides more flexibility, such as adding multiple Runner instances, choosing a number of threads, and providing time interval in a human-readable format such as "5m" for 5 minutes or "3h" for 3 hours, etc. You can check the detailed explanation [here](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/lifecycle/management/backgroundrunner/package-summary.html). I found it more convenient to use than Spring provided `@Scheduled` feature. The library is available as [maven artifact](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:com.github.michaelgantman%20AND%20a:MgntUtils) (including source code and javadoc) and on [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases/tag/1.5.0.7) (also with source code and javadoc) Also in the source code there is a working example of scheduled tasks running (See package "com.mgnt.lifecycle.management.backgroundrunner.example").

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered that in the project there is another scheduled task which lasts so long that it blocks all the others. Now I try to find out why it is so slow...

Answer (score 0):

create one class for configurations and create another class for scheduler.
don't forget to mark scheduler class as a spring component using @Component

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class MyClass {
    //this is your configuration class
}

//

@Component
public class TestScheduler{

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
    public void myMethod() {
        logger.info("hi");
    }
}
```